# Sort onclick only working once

Tags: jquery, sorting, onclick

I have a script that will sort a list of divs based on their data attribute. The sort functions are tied to clickable divs based on ID. Currently when I click one of the divs the items will sort correctly but only once. After sorting by ascending order(up) I'am unable to sort by descending(down) unless I refresh the page. 
jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4ttjxwme/2/
Below is the script, any help is appreciated!

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#down").on('click', function(){
                var sortedDivsDown = $(".unsorted").find("div").toArray().sort(sorterDown);
                $.each(sortedDivsDown, function (index, value) {
                    $(".loanIndicators ").append(value);
                });
                function sorterDown(b, a) {
                    return b.getAttribute('rel') - a.getAttribute('rel');
                };
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#up").on('click', function(){
              var sortedDivsUp = $(".unsorted").find("div").toArray().sort(sorterUp);
                $.each(sortedDivsUp, function (index, value) {
                    $(".loanIndicators ").append(value);
                });
                function sorterUp(a, b) {
                    return a.getAttribute('rel') - b.getAttribute('rel');
                };
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Care to provide a sample?

Comment: Just added a jsfiddle link to the post!

Comment: You're sorting the DIVs in `.unsorted`. But you're putting the sorted DIVs into `.loadIndicators`, so there's nothing left in `.unsorted` to sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using jquery object references for the sortedArrays `var sortedDivsDown = $(".unsorted").find("div").toArray().sort(sortDown);`, the second time around, the `.unsorted` div element is empty and the elements are now in the `.loanIndicators` div.

You can fix this by using the below selector to find the `indicator` div elements:

```
var sortedDivsDown = $(".unsorted,.loanIndicators").find("div").toArray().sort(sortDown);

var sortedDivsUp = $(".unsorted,.loanIndicators").find("div").toArray().sort(sortUp);
```

This will work in your case, since all the elements will be in either of the two div elements.

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dtneqxyb/3/)

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks Neil!